# basic filtering in django using queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

model.py

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    place = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    venue_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    rent = models.IntegerField()
    parking_area = models.IntegerField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.venue_Name
```

i want to filter this model using places which is selected in a droupdown list in one page when press filter display the model values from the database. though i read django doc i didnt understand the process of filtering

Comment: are you using a django form to get the selected places?

Comment: yes i using forms to get the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the part in the documentation you should be looking at - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters

The query that filters model values from the database is:

```
Venue.objects.filter(place='<dropdown-select>')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Venue.objects.filter(place= a[0])
```

a[0] being the value received from drop-down list